# Can we temporarily have different machine configuration?

Tags: cassandra

I am running 1 cluster of 12 nodes Cassandra on public cloud. As more and more load are coming, IOPS become an issue. Currently we are using pd-ssd as our backend storage and would like to upgrade into better disk. This new disk mandate minimum configuration for a VM to host those disk.

We can not afford any downtime, therefore we planned to upgrade the nodes on one-by-one scenario.

My Question, as per my understanding, all node on one cassandra cluster should have same machine configuration. Is there any way to accomplish our goal without sacrificing system stability ?

Thank you.

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a best-practice that all machines are equal - which can help problem diagnosis since it eliminates hardware differences as being a cause. There is nothing that mandates this has to be the case, and your upgrade is only going to make them slightly different for a short period of time - upgrading the hardware of each node, 1 at a time is fine.

Comment: We are planning to upgrade 1 nodes per day. Do you think this will be Ok ?

Comment: There is no reason to think it won't be, as long as you can perform the operation and stream data (as needed) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation to have a homogeneous really pertains to a steady state.

Given that the cluster will have different configurations during a migration period is really not a concern.

The challenge for you given that the you suggest the nodes are already IO-constrained is whether one day is sufficient to migrate a node. It is highly dependent on how busy the cluster is, how much data there is to migrate per node, and so on.

Good luck with the migration. Cheers!